# Why we initiate object inside constructor

Tags: java, class, constructor

Why we instantiate some object inside constructor and some outside. What are the advantage/ disadvantages of doing this.

```
public class HomePage_Util {
private Common_Functions cfObj = new Common_Functions();
HomePage_OR home_ORobj;
Logging logObj = new Logger();
public static String scptName;
public ArrayList<String> homeScriptMsgList = new ArrayList<String>();

public HomePage_Util(WebDriver driver) {
    home_ORobj = new HomePage_OR();
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, home_ORobj);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are initialized in constructors only when they are needed to initialize other objects in  a sequence. Like in your example first of all the object i.e. **home_ORobj = new HomePage_OR();** will be created as this object is needed to initialize the PageFactory elements in next step.

So if **home_ORobj = new HomePage_OR();** is not needed to initialize the PageFactory elements then you could write it out of the constructor i.e. globally.

Answer (score 0):

Code reuse is the main advantage of initializing elements in a constructor. Also initializing few things makes sense only when the object is created or constructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is basically for creating a `new object of a class`. When you create an object, a copy of all variable for that object is created and assigned `default value`.

The purpose of initiating some variables in constructor is to assigned the value at the time of creation of an object. So that you don't have to assigned value implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the writer of such code wasn't sure if home_ORobj would be initialized before the call to initElements() but the ones outside are initialized first so it doesn't matter.

Though if they depend on each other (i.e. use another in the parameters to the constructor) it's good to put them in the constructor as code formatters may re-order the list of elements breaking the the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Some objects requires few fields to be initialised in order to correctly construct that object before it being used. Constructor is called when the object is getting created, hence it is initialised in constructor.
2. You can have overloaded constructor with different initialistion for different scenarios.
3. You can always have a method called initializeValues and call it after you create an object rather than putting it in constructor.
4. Putting it in constructors will ensure that it is always called when you create an object.
5. Super class constructor is always called before the derived class constructor, so it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage is to avoid a static block to initialize static members.
AFAIK It's not exactly the same in the lifecycle of an object : constructor is executed after the firsts initializations.

Answer (score 0):

An instance field that is initiated outside a constructor is always going to be that way initially when a new object is created - for every instance. The ones initiated in a constructor may have some special meaning for the new instance such as the WebDriver in your example seems to have so it cannot be initiated elsewhere. A constructor that requires an instance of certain type to be passed as an argument does enforce design since it cannot be passed anything else and cannot be constructed without it.

A class may contain multiple constructors that may behave differently and instantiate different fields and leave others untouched (like when there are multiple purposes for a class, which actually may indicate bad design).

Additionally, if a class does not have a default constructor => upon deserialization no constructor's get called.